# Using fetchMore to fetch ALL data on component mount

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a situation where I need to fetch e.g. all articles posted by a user when a component is mounted. To get a user's articles I am using the following query:

```
const GET_USER_ARTICLES = gql`
    query getUserArticles($id: ID, $numArticles: Int!, $cursor: String) {
        user(id: $id) {
            id
            articles(first: $numArticles, after: $cursor, orderBy: "-created", state: "enabled") @connection(key: "userArticles") {
                edges {
                    node {
                        name
                    }
                }
                pageInfo {
                    endCursor
                    hasNextPage
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

If there is a next page I want to keep fetching more articles until I have ALL of them. Up until now I haven't had the need to do anything like this (normally I have a button the user can click "Load more" to fetch more articles for example, but now need to fetch everything without a user interacting with anything), so I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is.

An example of the query in React:

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 10;

const { data, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery<UserArticlesData, UserArticlesVariables>(
    GET_USER_ARTICLES,
    { variables: { id: userId, numArticles: PAGE_SIZE, cursor: null } },
);
```

I am a little lost how I can use the `fetchMore` to keep fetching until there aren't any more pages left, while also showing a loading state to the user. I'm also not sure this is the best way to go about this in the first place, so any suggestions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the API does not limit the page size, you could just provide an arbitrarily large number as the page size to get the remaining results. Assuming the page size can only be so big, though, you can do something like this:

```
const { data, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_USER_ARTICLES, {
  variables: { id: userId, numArticles: PAGE_SIZE, cursor: null },
  notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
})
const fetchRest = async () => {
  const { user: { articles: { pageInfo } } } = data
  const updateQuery = (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
    // Merge the fetchMoreResult and return the combined result
  }

  let hasNextPage = pageInfo.hasNextPage
  let cursor = pageInfo. endCursor

  while (hasNextPage) {
    const { data } = await fetchMore({
      variables: { id: userId, numArticles: PAGE_SIZE, cursor },
      updateQuery,
    })
    const { user: { articles: { pageInfo } } } = data
    hasNextPage = pageInfo.hasNextPage
    cursor = pageInfo. endCursor
  }
}
```

By setting `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` to `true`, `loading` will be updated whenever `fetchMore` is doing any fetching. Then we just loop until `hasNextPage` is called. `fetchMore` returns a Promise that resolves to the query result, so we can use the query response outside the `updateQuery` function.

Note that this is a rough example -- you might actually want to keep track of loading state yourself, for example. If your API has rate limiting, your logic should account for that as well. However hopefully this gives you a good starting point.

Edit:

If you need to get all the articles initially, I wouldn't use `useQuery` and `fetchMore` at all. The easiest workaround would be to manage the data and loading state yourself and utilize `client.query` instead.

```
const client = useApolloClient()
const [data, setData] = useState()
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const fetchAll = async () => {
  let hasNextPage = true
  let cursor = null
  let allResults = null

  while (hasNextPage) {
    const { data } = await client.query(GET_USER_ARTICLES, {
      variables: { id: userId, numArticles: PAGE_SIZE, cursor },
    })

    // merge data with allResults

    hasNextPage = pageInfo.hasNextPage
    cursor = pageInfo. endCursor
  }
  setLoading(false)
  setData(allResults)
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchAll()
}, [])
```

Comment: I've sort of got this to work, only problem I'm having is that it is getting called multiple times, resulting in the number of articles being larger than reality. I can't seem to figure out a solution -- I've tried using `useCallback` and `useEffect`, but it's still happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- what's being called multiple times? Based on the OP, it sounded like you needed a function to trigger in response to a user action (like a click). If you're trying to fetch all the articles **initially**, the above won't work.

Comment: @vwos See my edit for one way you could handle fetching everything on mount, assuming that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry that's my mistake: I meant that I normally used `fetchMore` to fetch more data when a user clicks a button, but now needed to fetch everything on mount. I'll edit the OP to make it more clear. Your answer is exactly what I needed either way!

Comment: I'd recommend the `fetchMore` approach in any case where you want to retain the cache to support mutations that modify the cache somewhere else.